# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on Natural Join in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get this to work in Oracle Apex and I keep getting the "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error and I can't figure it out. I'd really appreciate some help.

```
SELECT Genre, ROUND(AVG(NumberofStreams)) AS "Average Number of Streams"
FROM (SELECT Artist.Genre, Songs.NumberofStreams, Songs.SongID
  FROM Songs 
  NATURAL JOIN Artist ON Songs.ArtistID = Artist.ArtistID)
GROUP BY Genre;
```

Comment: Is it an error to include the `ON` clause o a JOIN when it is a NATURAL JOIN? I.e., should it just be `NATURAL JOIN Artist)`?

Answer (score 4):

As per [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html), Natural join is used to join 2 tables based on all matching column names.

**So the problem in your query is that you cannot specify a specific column you should join on, as natural join would join based on all matching column names.**

So in your case, if you want to join based on ArtistID, and assuming that the two tables dont have any other matching columns, Use below as mentioned by Phil in comments too.

```
SELECT Genre, ROUND(AVG(NumberofStreams)) AS "Average Number of Streams"
FROM 
(SELECT Artist.Genre, Songs.NumberofStreams, Songs.SongID
  FROM Songs 
  NATURAL JOIN
  Artist 
 )
GROUP BY Genre;
```

OR, If there are multiple matching columns, but you want to join only based on `ArtistID`, you can use `USING` clause with `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT Genre, ROUND(AVG(NumberofStreams)) AS "Average Number of Streams"
FROM 
(SELECT Artist.Genre, Songs.NumberofStreams, Songs.SongID
  FROM Songs 
  INNER JOIN
  Artist 
  USING (ArtistID)
 )
GROUP BY Genre;
```

But to avoid confusion, it is best to use `INNER JOIN` with `ON` clause, as you can see from the query, which columns are being joined. And it can be used while joining columns with different names also.

```
SELECT Genre, ROUND(AVG(NumberofStreams)) AS "Average Number of Streams"
FROM 
(SELECT Artist.Genre, Songs.NumberofStreams, Songs.SongID
  FROM Songs 
  INNER JOIN
  Artist 
  ON Songs.ArtistID = Artist.ArtistID
 )
GROUP BY Genre;
```

Comment: I think by "normal join" you mean "**inner** join"; and when you say "in Inner Join" you mean "in the subquery".

Comment: Yes. Replaced all `normal join` and `join` with `inner join` to avoid confusion.